# oci connect(): ORA-12154

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g, oci8

I'm having trouble with Oracle connection , I'm facing the error message : oci connect(): ORA-12154
I'm using Xampp port:80 
oracle g11 express 
PHP 5.5.30

package installed is:

OCI8 Support    enabled
OCI8 DTrace Support disabled
OCI8 Version    2.0.8

Oracle Run-time Client Library Version  11.2.0.4.0
Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version  11.2

my app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = GLORY-PC)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

the test code is:

```
$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'hr123', 'XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e\['message'\] , ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM employees');
oci_execute($stid);
echo "
<table border='1'>
\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "
<tr>
\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "
<td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : " ") . "</td>
\n";
    }
    echo "
</tr>
\n";
}
echo "
</table>
\n";
```

thank you

Comment: What error message are you getting? Can you add that to your question?

Comment: oci connect(): ORA-12154 , please help

Comment: Probably it means that you showed us the wrong tnsnames.ora. Try ezconnect instead: `$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'hr123', 'GLORY-PC:1522/XE');` .

Comment: @stee1rat  problem solved I can't thank you enough god bless you